# Policy for questions about older versions of Blender

Tags: discussion

There have been questions about older versions of Blender, in some cases this seems like the user could have updated their installation before asking especially if its an area thats getting large updates for each release.

Also with Blender theres rarely a good reason to stick to old version.

In the case when a question asks about some problem thats been fixed in a newer version of blender I would be inclined to close the question, but is this good practice?

Comment: I personally think we should not accept any questions pre **2.5x** but let's see what people say, this was partly the reason why we didn't want version specific tags. It might encourage questions like that.

Comment: I have to agree with @iKlsR except for one thing: certain addons and scripts are specific to 2.4x. I don't think there will be too many questions like that, but there may be a few. I don't think most of the 2.4x questions most users are asking are relating to this anyway.

Comment: @iKlsR, You say. pre-2.5x but why would we even answer 2.5x specific questions? Theres always the very small chance that there is a valid question for an old Blender version --- but for the most part, I would think anyone asking a question for 2.5x would be advised to upgrade in the case where new versions work differently (or resolves the issue they ask about). This still begs the question `How old is too old` ?

Comment: @ideasman42 I did just to set a reasonable limit as this was where Blender changed direction, I know people who are still using 2.5x because they fear or rather *know* that upgrading might break their pipeline/workflow etc. A good point indeed, we need to know where to cap it.

Answer (score 7):

We could choose to leave this topic open (and simply not have any policy).

In the same way stack-overflow doesn't exclude developers from asking questions about Python-1.0 for example,

Users might just have to accept if they ask questions about older versions, they might not get a good answer, or the answer may be to upgrade.

Having a policy could reduce `noise` --- questions about issues resolved in newer versions, but since there is not so much incentive to keep using older Blender versions, this may be worrying about a problem that isn't.

*Note that this is more to post a point-of-view, if others share - it can be up-voted*

Answer (score 3):

2.49 is still available for download on some platforms (for example the irie PPA has it), but I don't think we should support versions older than 2.5x, regardless.

Supporting older versions can lead to a lot of confusion and to abandoned, unanswered questions. Our policy on Ask Ubuntu for example is to only support Ubuntu versions that are not yet at their End Of Life.

This would work perfectly for Blender IMHO.

Comment: Even supporting 2.5x I think is too old, If you are wanting to use Blender why use a version from 2011? (2.59)

Comment: @ideasman42: Because it comes with your distribution.  One reason a distribution is so nice, is that it takes care of all software updates for you.  I don't want to check if firefox, blender, libreoffice, gimp, etc etc have a new version.  I just want to run my distribution's upgrade program and be done with it.  Now I personally like to use the new features of Blender, so I chose to get it from the site.  But I definitely don't want to recommend, or even require this from people who just have a question and are happy with their packaged version.

Answer (score 3):

People can ask questions about pre `current Trunk` releases, but it will be down to a dedicated few to bother engaging with localized issues that will effect only 10 people on the planet.

We already have a policy to avoid localization, unless the answer leads to some form of enlightenment and lifts the question into a wider context.

perhaps. a canned response with the core of this discussion:

> 'This question might not get many answers or indeed a satisfactory solution as it
>   relates to a pre 2.6 addon or feature, please realize that the site is
>   run based on the best intentions to answer all questions, but
>   especially those that are likely to impact, and be useful to, the most
>   users'

Answer (score 2):

As the age of Blender and this StackExchange site grow, we will end up with questions that are "too old". It is inevitable. The best we can do is tag things early and often. If we stay in the habit, then users can filter out "old" results in their searches for questions that have already been asked. If you want a good example of this question answered, look at any of the other StackExchange sites that have been around for much longer.

When Blender 3.0 comes out, we can't make all these 2.x questions suddenly irrelevant.